# The Method add(Element) is not applicable for the arguments (String[])

Tags: java, swing, pdf, itext

I am trying to create a paragraph using array element to write it in the pdf file, if I add just one line for example **paragraph.add("This is the content");** its working fine;

When I tried with an array it gives an error [image: snippet]

Please give me directions to fix this, thanks.

The code:

```
public void readStuff(){

String[] arrayName = new String[7];

try{
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(new FileInputStream("My First PDF Doc.pdf"));

    arrayName[0] = "PDF version: " + reader.getPdfVersion();
    arrayName[1] = "Number of pages " + reader.getNumberOfPages();
    arrayName[2] = "File length: " + reader.getFileLength();
    arrayName[3] = "Is it encrypted: " + reader.isEncrypted();
    arrayName[4] = "Width of the page 1: " + reader.getPageSize(1).getWidth();
    arrayName[5] = "Height of the page 1: " + reader.getPageSize(1).getHeight();
    arrayName[6] = "Rotation of page 1: " + reader.getPageRotation(1);

    for(int x = 0; x < 7; x++){
        System.out.println(arrayName[x]);
    }

    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("My First PDF Doc.pdf"));
    document.open();

    Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
    paragraph.add(arrayName);
    document.add(paragraph);
    document.close();


} catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
};
```

**Error:**

```
The Method add(Element) in the type Paragraph is not applicable for the arguments (String[])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace `paragraph.add(arrayName);` with this

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayName.length; i++) {
    paragraph.add(arrayName[i]);
}
```